# Keras TensorBoard visulize Conv Kernels

Tags: python, keras, tensorboard

I am using Keras with TensorFlow as backend.
Now i want to use the TensorBoard callback to visualize my conv layer kernels.
But i can only see the first conv layer kernel in TensorBoard and my Dense layers at the end.
For the other conv layers i can just the the bias values and not the kernels.

Here is my sample code for the Keras model.

```
tb = TensorBoard(
    log_dir=log_dir, 
    histogram_freq=epochs, 
    write_images=True)

# Define the DNN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(width, height, depth), name="conv1"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, name="conv2"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, name="conv3"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, name="conv4"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, name="features"))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

# Print the DNN layers
model.summary()

# Train the DNN
lr = 1e-3
optimizer = Adam(lr=lr)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, verbose=1, 
batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, 
validation_data=(x_test, y_test), 
callbacks=[tb])
```

And this is what i see in TensorBoard.
(I minimized the Kernels of my first conv layer)
[TB Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuiC5.png)

What am i missing to visulize all my kernels?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected (but not specified in the documentation) behaviour of the Tensorboard callback. See the answer on this [related bug report of Tensorboard GitHub page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2240#issuecomment-580891798):

> The TensorBoard Keras callback calls tf.summary.image without
>   overriding the default for max_outputs, so there’s no way to visualize
>   more than the first 3 kernels via the callback at this time.

You need to visualize the kernels with your own call of the `tf.summary.image`.